# Cedet 1.1 with Emacs 24.2 in Windows cannot parse c++ header files without extension

Tags: windows-7, emacs, c++

Emacs 24.2, Cedet 1.1, Windows 7

Visual Studio 10.0 Include directory

```
(add-to-list 'load-path " ~/.emacs.d/cedet-1.1/common")
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")

(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)

(require 'semantic-decorate-include)

(require 'semantic-ia)

(global-ede-mode nil)

(setq-mode-local c-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                 '(project local unloaded system recursive))
(setq-mode-local c++-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                 '(project local unloaded system recursive))

(semantic-add-system-include "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VS/Include" 'c++-mode)
```

When writing c++ program and include, say, `iostream`, it navigates to this include file, but is not able to parse it. On the other hand when include, say, `stdlib.h` it parses successfully such an include.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some workaround. Need to tell C lexer to parse Microsoft include files with defines like this

```
(defun windows-semantic-hook ()
    (setq microsoft-base-dir 
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include")
    (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
               (concat microsoft-base-dir "/crtdefs.h"))
    (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
               (concat microsoft-base-dir "/yvals.h"))
    (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
               (concat microsoft-base-dir "/vadefs.h"))
    (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
               (concat microsoft-base-dir "/comdefsp.h"))
    (semantic-add-system-include microsoft-base-dir 'c++-mode)
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons microsoft-base-dir 'c++-mode)))

(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'windows-semantic-hook)
```

Now semantic parser feels better (but not completely good) and is able to parse some includes like `<string>`, `<map>` etc.